# Are there methods to determine the equilibrium points of the general three bodies problem?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, equilibrium, phase-space, three-body-problem

Starting from the three second-order differential equations, I have written the problem in the form of a system (from a modelling point of view): $$\mathbf{\dot{x}}=\mathbf{f(\mathbf{x})}$$
where $\mathbf{x}$ is a vector with 18 components (9 are the positions' components and 9 the speeds' components). Now I'd like to study the equilibrium points, this implies solving the non-linear system:
$$\mathbf{f(\mathbf{x})}=\mathbf{0}$$
This system has 9 unknowns (the positions) and I don't see any easy way to solve it analitically. I could try to solve it numerically but in that case I need a starting point near an equilibrium point for the solving algorithm, but I have no idea of where equilibrium points are (neither if they exist). Someone expert could give me a hint?

Comment: What do you know about your function $\mathbf{f}$?

Comment: I think that is a very complicated question in general. People usually study limits of the problem. You could try for instance to start in the limit $m_1$ << $m_2$, $m_3$ where the stationary points are known as Lagrange points. Then you can slowly increase $m_1$ and use numerics (e.g. a Newton Raphson algorithm) to see what happens to your stationary points.

Comment: I was thinking that maybe in the way I wrote the problem there are no equilibrium points. Indeed at the equilibrium the speeds and the accelerations of the three bodies should be zero and so the gravitational forces acting on each bodies balanced. But I can't figure out such a configuration. @BySymmetry

Comment: What do you mean by "equilibrium" points? A system of three particles inside a presumed confining potential does not exhibit thermodynamic behavior and does not have a thermodynamic equilibrium state. At best it has a point (or points) of mechanical equilibrium in which the net force in all particles is zero. You must be more explicit about what you are trying to do.